# How to convert string time to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, type-conversion

I have some values like '1967' and 'May 1976'. In python, how can I convert

`1967` to `01-01-1967` and `May 1976` to `05-01-1976`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Comment: => e.g. with [strptime and strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works but idk if thats a good way.

```
import datetime

def year_to_date(year):
    asdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(year, '%Y')
    print(asdate.date())


def month_year_to_date(month_year):
    asdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(month_year, '%B %Y')
    print(asdate.date())    


year_to_date("1967")
month_year_to_date("May 1967")
```

https://stackabuse.com/converting-strings-to-datetime-in-python/

makes a good explanation to this.

Comment: instead of printing the .date(), you could add `strftime('%d-%m-%Y')`

Comment: I would probably change the `print()` to `return`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `dateutil` library to parse your date strings.

Install with Pip:

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

Sample:

```
from dateutil import parser
    
date = parser.parse("May 1976")
print(date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
```

This provides a lot of other functionalities as well which you can check out here in the documentation: https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse